# mysql write a query to cross check multiple columns against a string in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write some sql to query multiple columns in one table against one column in another table and return the matching data.

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`userkey` int, `username` varchar(255),`customproperty1` varchar(255),`customproperty2` varchar(255),`customproperty3` varchar(255))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`userkey`, `username`, `customproperty1`,`customproperty2`,`customproperty3`)
VALUES
    (1, 'STOI07012104', 'orgL1','org L2','org L3'),
    (2, 'STOI07012105', 'orgL1','org L4','org L5')
;

CREATE TABLE ents
    (`entkeykey` int, `customproperty1` varchar(255))
;
    
    INSERT INTO ents
    (`entkeykey`, `customproperty1`)
VALUES
    (1, 'orgL1(1234#1223),org L12(2342#235456),org l22(34546#34534#3547),org L5(34546#34534#3547),org L5(34546#34534#3547)')
;
```

This is what i would like returned :

| userkey | matchedOrg | orgApprovers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orgL1 | 1234#1223 |
| 2 | org L5 | 34546#34534#3547 |

Thanks in advance.
SG

Comment: Provide your sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And show desired output as formatted table.

Comment: I'd start by normalizing property fields into one, and another field to that of their no's in another table, ideally changing the DB design. Then it is rather trivial to check the condition for only a single field.

Comment: @Nae, i agree, but unfortunately i dont have control of the DB, just have the ability to run SQL and pull out data.

Comment: @Superglu how about creating temporary tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a temporary normalized table, and apply the same filter on the single field:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users_normalized;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_users_normalized
SELECT userkey, username, 1 AS PropertyType, customproperty1 AS Value
FROM users u
UNION ALL
SELECT userkey, username, 2 AS PropertyType, customproperty2 AS Value
FROM users u
UNION ALL
SELECT userkey, username, 3 AS PropertyType, customproperty3 AS Value
FROM users u
;

SELECT *
FROM tmp_users_normalized tun
JOIN ents e ON tun.Value LIKE '%etc%'
;
```